# MYSQL - Order timestamp values ascending in order, from newest to oldest?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, sql-order-by

I have come across a problem when trying to order certain results by their timestamp value.

I would like these results displayed from the newest, to the oldest based on the timestamp values.

So to explain this, imagine that there were 3 results:

```
2012-07-11 17:34:57
2012-07-11 17:33:28
2012-07-11 17:33:07
```

This result set would be what I would require, but given the following query

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM randomTable
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

I get:

```
2012-07-11 17:34:57
2012-07-11 17:33:07
2012-07-11 17:33:28
```

This is as it is sorted by numerical value and `07` comes before `28`.

If i sort in descending order I get

```
2012-07-11 17:33:07
2012-07-11 17:33:28
2012-07-11 17:34:57
```

Which is what I am looking for... But it is in reverse.

So my question is fairly simple, how could I sort these values in ascending order as I have described?

EDIT:

[image: The problem]

EDIT2:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_quotations` (
 `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `quoteNumber` int(100) NOT NULL,
 `lastModified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `userId` int(100) NOT NULL,
 `manufacturer` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `modelNumber` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `productDesc` varchar(1000) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `quoteNumber` (`quoteNumber`,`lastModified`,`userId`,`manufacturer`,`modelNumber`,`timestamp`),
 KEY `productDesc` (`productDesc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci
```

Comment: Your result set can't be right.  `2012-07-11 17:34:57` will never come before `2012-07-11 17:33:07` when ordered ascending.

Comment: Check the other parts of the time stamp. Are they identical? Looks like you have overlooked something

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/421ce/1 Something doesn't feel right.

Comment: Additionally, your descending order (want to be like this) is not possible, either.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs These are the exact same values as in the timestamp field in my table in mysql. It is the exact same query that I am using in phpmyadmin except my table name differs. That is the result set for sure! After double checking... I am 100% sure that this is the problem.

Comment: Should I be using `date_format` in the order by clause??

Comment: @BlackberryFan, that is not possible.  Even if your timestamp column was a string, the order will never be as you describe.  It just does not work that way.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Please see the edit in my question. Could this be because I am using a customer datetime format?

Comment: @BlackberryFan, put the backticks on your `timestamp` column, you are probably ordering by the reserved keyword.  You can tell this is not right because :34 will always come after :33, so ignoring the :07 vs :28 issue, other things are wrong.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Thanks for your input, I did not think of that. But the result set is still the same.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd you've created the column "dt" as "datetime". The user has stated it's a timestamp. Anyway even when I've changed it to "timestamp" (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca47/2) it still returns proper results.

Comment: Maybe your system needs a dictionary to learn the difference(and meaning) of the terms `ASCENDING` and `DESCENDING`

Comment: @Nerd-Herd It is not a datetime field, sorry. I am referring to the timestamp field specially. (its a bit more down)

Comment: After seeing `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in there, I edited sqlfiddle too, and lo-and-behold: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ceab/1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your query :

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM randomTable
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

is perfect. But I doubt about the results you have presented in your posting.
You posted :

```
2012-07-11 17:34:57
2012-07-11 17:33:07
2012-07-11 17:33:28
```

But results in your sqlbox shows :

```
2012-07-11 17:34:57
2012-07-15 17:33:07
2012-07-15 17:33:28
```

Which are perfectly right.

Is that a typo error in your posting?
If no, then try the following :

```
SELECT timestamp( `timestamp` ) as 'timestamp'
FROM randomTable
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Check your create statement for the table.  I expect your timestamp column is really a string.

```
Show create table tablename;
```

Comment: Almost definitely; problem is, even for a string it is not ordered correctly.

Comment: Ray, thanks for your reply, I have edited my answer to include the requested info. It is the full output of what you have requested.

Comment: @BlackberryFan See the answer below someone else put... looks like you just miss read the timestamps based on your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

if you write the query as:

```
select q.`timestamp`
from user_quotations as q
order by q.`timestamp`
limit 30
```

you should have them ordered properly.

If not, there is a problem with the timestamp data.  Look for leading/ trailing spaces, odd characters, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and your effprt, but this still returns the same result set. Could this not have something to do with the date format I have used as it is not the standard? Or possibly the tables charset, although i dont see how this could affect the timestamp field.

Comment: regardless of the date format, if it's a datetime field, it should always order correctly.  It's possible your browser/ phpMyAdmin is caching your results, but there is no way (unless you have a truly broken MySQL instance) that you should ever see the columns ordered that way with the above query.

Comment: It is the timestamp field as I did specify. There is a datetime field but it is not the one that I am requesting results from.

Answer (score 1):

screen shot shows two of the results from 15th and one from 11th. Probably affects the order a wee bit.