# php mysql order by timestamp is incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have database records such as below

```
Name Date(timestamp) Time(timestamp)
```

I want to order them by time DESC. But it shows me incorrect order. It shows now:

```
Name 19:00
Other 18:30
One more 19:00
```

As you can see hours are not going from earliest to latest. I want it to be like this:

```
Other 18:30
Name 19:00
One more 19:00
```

What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='".$date."' ORDER BY book_time DESC
```

Comment: I don't understand the example, pls can you improve it?

Comment: Can you setup an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Timestamp() for specifying that you expect the fields you wanna extract data from as timestamps.

something like this:

```
SELECT timestamp( `timestamp` ) as 'timestamp'
FROM randomTable
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

it would be great if you can post screenshots of your output to make the issue clearer.

Comment: It is exactly as i posted above. i want to see 18:30 first in the list rather than 19:00

Comment: To see the entire response look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11493788/4911780

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that select only for the date that you want? Because I think that select multiple date not only one.

Also for what you want you need to use ASC instead of DESC.

Because I have try and it's work for me. This is my simple code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE date = '2016-02-10' ORDER BY time ASC";
$res = $DB->query($sql);

while($enr = $res->fetch()){
    var_dump($enr);
}
```

With this DB :

[image: Database on MySQL]

And the result is :

```
array (size=8)
  'id' => string '4' (length=1)
   0 => string '4' (length=1)
  'date' => string '2016-02-10' (length=10)
   1 => string '2016-02-10' (length=10)
  'time' => string '01:00:07' (length=8)
   2 => string '01:00:07' (length=8)

array (size=8)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
   0 => string '3' (length=1)
  'date' => string '2016-02-10' (length=10)
   1 => string '2016-02-10' (length=10)
  'time' => string '02:03:05' (length=8)
   2 => string '02:03:05' (length=8)
```

The result is order in the ASC order like you want

Hope that helps you.