# Five most recent records by timestamp using SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timestamp, command

I need some help on that: there's a website of HTML5 Generator which has to keep and show the last 5 codes generated by a given user. I have created some tables using MySQL, but I'm struggling with the SQL command itself. How do I show five most recent records from the history table? I guess this requires timestamp check.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Show us some of that history table, and the expected result.

Comment: [ORDER BY  timestamp duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493463/mysql-order-timestamp-values-ascending-in-order-from-newest-to-oldest)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where user = 'given_user' order by timestamp_column desc limit 5;
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: for a given user we are selecting records in descending order and limiting it to 5 records.