# MySQL Order rows by date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order my rows by the date that each row has.

One row has `2016-09-15 15:36` and one has `2016-08-15 13:12` How would i order them so that the highest one is at top?

Their row is called `th_activity` and i know that in a normal query, you would do something like `SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY th_activity DESC` but i believe i know the problem. I use varchar as the type for the row. I'm not really sure what the length/value should be for date if that's what i must use.

If someone can explain how i would order this properly, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't quite get why this is a problem for you. the beauty of ISO 8601-like date/time is that it can be sorted by alphabetical rules and still make sense...so even if the column is varchar, you should still get it sorted. if not, there may be whitespace characters before the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have set the type of column as `timstamp` instead of `varchar`, which doesn't care about the length of data (only that while inserting data take care about the format).

Check this question to ordery by timestamp:

[MYSQL - Order timestamp values ascending in order, from newest to oldest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493463/mysql-order-timestamp-values-ascending-in-order-from-newest-to-oldest)

```
SELECT th_activity
FROM tableName
ORDER BY timestamp desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, Works perfect now!

Answer (score 4):

If your date is year-month-day hour:minute, you can order alphabetically without any problems, so `ORDER BY th_activity DESC` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need a str_to_date conversion

```
select * from threads 
ORDER BY str_to_date(th_activity, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a data type

```
datetime
```

and use the same select you wrote in the question :

```
order by th_activity DESC
```